# How to write the fraction on two line?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write the fraction on two line in LaTeX like this.

[image]

how to make it please?

Regards ,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!. Try `\splitfrac` from `mathtools`. If you will provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE) with your equation, I can show you how to rewrote your equation :)

Answer (score 2):

There is the `\splitfrac` command, from `mathtools`, which is precisely designed for that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\begin{equation}
    A = \left\{\varepsilon_G b +\dfrac{\varepsilon_{HG} bK[H]_t}{\splitfrac{1+0.5\big(-(1-K[G]_t +K[H]_t)}{ + √{(1-K[G]_t +K[H]_t)² + 4K[G]_t}\big)}}\right\}%
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This forum is good.  Thank you for learning something new. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `aligned`-environment from package `amsmath`.  The `&` will align the different arts to each other.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    f =& \frac{a + b + b}{e - f - g} \\
    & \frac{h * i * j}{k + l - m}
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]